# Can't continue Ubuntu installation due to disk space

Tags: disk, disk-usage

I have about 44 GB disk space, and I need only 8.6 GB disk space to continue Ubuntu installation. What's the issue.

Comment: Please edit your question to show us the complete output demonstrating the problem. How can we reproduce it?

Comment: And you need unallocated space to install. Free space in any already existing partition doesn't count, the installer will not and should not touch those partitions.